# I am using langchain to chat with my database I want json format as output which includes fieldname as key

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, openai-api, langchain

I am working on Natural language to query your SQL Database using LangChain powered by ChatGPT.I am using  Langchain's SQL database to chat with my database, it returns answers in the sentence I want the answer in JSON format so I have designed a prompt but sometimes it is not giving the proper format. I have a projects table in my DB that has id, `project_name`, area, price, `bhk`, and amenities fields.

```
Q="project in Bandra area"  
Ans="{'id': 5, 'project_name': 'Anantara Abode', 'area': 'Bandra', 'price': 4500000, 'bhk': 3, 'amenities': 'None'}"  
Q="Flats under 65 lakhs"  
A={1: {'project_name': 'Anantara', 'area': 'Shahibaug', 'price': 5000000, 'bhk': 3, 'amenities': 'Club house,Swimming Pool'},  
2: {'project_name': 'Vivanta', 'area': 'Shilaj', 'price': 7000000, 'bhk': 2, 'amenities': 'Club house, Swimming Pool'},  
3: {'project_name': 'Athence', 'area': 'SG highway', 'price': 5500000, 'bhk': 2, 'amenities': 'Garden, Temple'},  
4: {'project_name': 'Anantara Alpines', 'area': 'Hebatpur', 'price': 6000000, 'bhk': 3, 'amenities': 'None'},  
5: {'project_name': 'Anantara Abode', 'area': 'Bopal', 'price': 4500000, 'bhk': 3, 'amenities': 'None'}}
```

In the second answer "id" field name is not included as a key.

```
%%capture  
!pip install -q langchain  
!pip install -q openai
```

```py
from langchain import OpenAI , SQLDatabase , SQLDatabaseChain  
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
input_db= SQLDatabase.from_uri('sqlite:///main.db')  
llm_1=OpenAI(openai_api_key=openai_api_key,temperature=0)

db_agent=SQLDatabaseChain(llm = llm_1,database = input_db,verbose=True)

QUERY ="""
Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct sql query to run, then look at the results      of the query and return the answer in dictonary format and include id fieldname in all answers.
Use the following format.  
Question: "Question here"   
SQLQuery: "SQL Query to run include id in all queries"  
SQLResult: "Result of the SQLQuery include id in all result"  
Answer: "Final answer should be in dictionary format include id fieldname in all answers"  
{question}"""

question = QUERY.format(question="project in Bandra area")   
db_agent.run(question)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup your prompt with an example, add this in your prompt

```
"Final answer should be in the following format:

{"data": [{"column1": "value1", "column2": "value2", "column3": "value3",...},"2": {"column1": "value1", "column2": "value2", "column3": "value3",...}, ...}]}

Ensure that all strings are enclosed in double quotes.

For example:
{"data":[{"id":"1","project_name":"Vivanta","area":"Shilaj",...},{"id":"3","project_name":"Athence","area":"SG Highway",...}, ...}]}"
```